Chrome not updating for month
Why I have chrome not updating for month? I get this error https://imgur.com/a/kubuntu-chrome-something-changed-Cu60JUO
Opening that button FINISH UPDATE opens chrome deb download link. but i have already cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
======== google-chrome.list.distUpgrade

### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###

# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.

# deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main # disabled on upgrade to noble

======= & google-chrome.sources

Enabled: no

Types: deb

URIs: https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/

Suites: stable

Components: main

Signed-By:

-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----


It seems like you updated your system in the past from ??? to Noble. During this process the update manager disables all package sources except the original Ubuntu sources, to prevent potential conflicts while upgrading your Ubuntu to a newer release. After the upgrade process ran successfully, you need to re-enable other sources than the Ubuntu sources manually.
In the given case, open the file named google-chrome.sources as shown by you with an editor with root privileges (e.g. by navigating in the terminal to the folder where the file google-chrome.sources is located, then enter sudo nano google-chrome.sources), go to the line Enabled: no and replace it with Enabled: yes. Save the file and close the editor.
Run sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade in the terminal and the latest stable release of Chrome should be installed. Plus you should receive update for Chrome automatically again.

What Upgrade in some 30. august has to do with anything? I did that in 30. august. With upgrade chrome was even removed. I needed to install it again. After that all the time updates were comming. So after upgrade was comming but only month ago, which btw is next to next release of 24.10 it stopped updating. But i didnt update to 24.10. Im only upgrading to LTS versions so next time ill do it in 26.04
So why and when was Enabled set to no?

The bottom line is: you are sitting in front of your computer, not us. You know what you did, not us. And yes, you must have triggered something which disabled the source for Chrome. Whatever it is - we cannot know.

i didnt trigger. If that what happened in 24.04 upgrade, then maybe in date around 24.10 it happened again, but that means here is a bug since i didnt upgrade to 24.10. I allways do only LTS so i have 24.04 LTS

Try this:
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

Here's where you'll find out more.
